# Limiting and Filtering IEnumerable Results in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sample

I have a C#  IEnumerable for Tshirts called tshirtResults. I could have say 4000 tshirts to start with from within this object I decide I only want to take say `500` of them. (Meaning I want limit this by `500`).

From there I want to be sure that I take `250` of the *red t-shirts*(`.IsRed`) and `250` of the blue *t-shirts* (`.IsBlue`) and  make sure they are captured within the `tshirtResults` object? . How to do? Is it possible? Any direction would be appreciated. -Jason

```
    IEnumerable<TShirts> tshirtResults;

    int Limit =500

    if (Limit > 0) {
      int numberToTakeofeachcolor = Limit / 2;

      // What to do ?
    
    }
```

Comment: What if there is only 200 blue t-shirts in the enumerable?

Comment: Good point .In that case take all 200 of the blue and then 300 of the red I guess.

Comment: What does `make sure they are captured within the tshirtResults object` mean? Does that mean that you want to remove them from the `tshirtResults` collection?

Comment: You can't modify an `IEnumerable` object, you need to provide at least an `ICollection` object or create a new `IEnumerable` object.

Comment: Too much blah, blah in this thread about how many T-shirts there may, or not, be.  [@shingo is right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76281427/limiting-and-filtering-ienumerable-results-in-c-sharp#comment134517572_76281427).  SO DO THIS:  Ignore everything written on this thread  and [Read MS documentation about List class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-7.0). Using `List.Find()`, for example, writing simple filtering expressions is not difficult

Comment: @JasonLivengood what about if there are only 200 red shirts? The same? If so, Dmitry Bychenko's answer looks good.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest storing a sample in a buffer (at most `2 * (redLimit + redLimit)` items. In the worst case we may return all blue or all read shirts) and then after analyzing *limits* (*desired* number of red and blue - `250` and `250`) and *counts* (*actual* number of red and blue, say `400` and `210`) return the best fit from the buffer - `290` and `210`:

```
private static IEnumerable<TShirt> Sampling(
  IEnumerable<TShirt> shirts, int redLimit, int blueLimit) {

  var buffer = new List<TShirt>(2 * (redLimit + redLimit));
  int redCount = 0;
  int blueCount = 0;

  foreach (var shirt in shirts) {
    if (shirt.IsRed && redCount < redLimit + blueLimit) {
      redCount += 1;
      buffer.Add(shirt);
    }
    else if (shirt.IsBlue && blueCount < redLimit + blueLimit) {
      blueCount += 1;
      buffer.Add(shirt);
    }

    if (redCount >= redLimit && blueCount >= blueLimit)
      break; // we have enough red and enough blue
  }

  if (redCount < redLimit) // too few red, try to adjust blue
    blueCount = Math.Min(blueCount, redLimit + blueLimit - redCount);

  if (blueCount < blueLimit) // too few blue, try to adjust red
    redCount = Math.Min(redCount, redLimit + blueLimit - blueCount);

  if (redCount >= redLimit && blueCount >= blueLimit) {
    redCount = redLimit;    // enough red and blue
    blueCount = blueLimit;
  }

  foreach (var shirt in buffer)
    if (shirt.IsRed && --redCount >= 0)
      yield return shirt;
    else if (shirt.IsBlue && --blueCount >= 0)
      yield return shirt;
}
```

Usage:

```
IEnumerable<TShirts> originalShirts = ... 

...

IEnumerable<TShirts> tshirtResults = Sampling(originalShirts, 250, 250);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// start with the full data
IEnumerable<TShirts> tshirtResults = SomeLargeEnumerable();

// now restrict to 250 red and 250 blue:
tshirtResults = tshirtResults.Where(t => t.IsRed).Take(250).
    Concat(tshirtResults.Where(t => t.IsBlue).Take(250));
```

If there are only 200 red or blue shirts, this would stop short of the 500. You *could* do some things like count, or construct a list and check the length, but those are slow (they add extra iterations of the sequence, and may even force allocating new memory to hold all the object references).

Instead, I expect you'll need to iterate this soon anyway... otherwise what's the point? Given that, you may be able to count as you iterate, and then fill in the missing tshirts at the end if and only if you find the count was short.

Comment: Won't work if there are 200 and 300 shirts. That was added in the comments

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea of using a buffer, as suggested in [Dmitry Bychenko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76281427/limiting-and-filtering-ienumerable-results-in-c-sharp#answer-76281871). My approach to using a buffer is slightly different. The logic goes as follows:

1. Loop through all the t-shirt objects

   1. **If** the t-shirt is **red** and we **haven't reached the target count** for red t-shirts yet,
      `yield return` the t-shirt
   2. **Else**, if the t-shirt is **blue** and we **haven't reached the target count** for blue t-shirts yet,
      `yield return` the t-shirt
   3. **Else**, if the t-shirt is **red or blue**,
      put it in the buffer
   4. **Now**, if we **have reached the target count** for both colors,
      leave the method (`yield break`)
2. After looping through all the t-shirts, the missing t-shirt count is `yield return`ed from the buffer

---

Note that since we leave the method (`yield break`) at the moment when all desired red and blue t-shirts have been found (step 1.4),

- we will only reach the code *after* the `foreach` loop (step 2) if we need to select t-shirts from the buffer to reach the total t-shirt target count
- *if* the buffer is populated, it will only be populated with t-shirts that all have the same color. Hence, we do not need a separate buffer for each color. (The 'common buffer' usage is only feasible for this particular scenario where we only have *two* colors of interest.)

---

A possible implementation of this logic is:

```
private static IEnumerable<TShirt> GetSelection(
    IEnumerable<TShirt> allTShirts,
    int targetCountRed,
    int targetCountBlue)
{
    var selectionCountRed = 0;
    var selectionCountBlue = 0;
    
    var buffer = new List<TShirt>();
    
    foreach (var tShirt in allTShirts)
    {
        if (tShirt.IsRed && selectionCountRed < targetCountRed)
        {
            selectionCountRed++;
            yield return tShirt;
        }
        else if (tShirt.IsBlue && selectionCountBlue < targetCountBlue)
        {
            selectionCountBlue++;
            yield return tShirt;
        }
        else if (tShirt.IsRed || tShirt.IsBlue)
        {
            buffer.Add(tShirt);
        }
        
        if (selectionCountRed == targetCountRed && selectionCountBlue == targetCountBlue)
        {
            yield break;
        }
    }
    
    var targetCount = targetCountRed + targetCountBlue;
    var selectionCount = selectionCountRed + selectionCountBlue;
    
    var missingCount = targetCount - selectionCount;

    foreach (var bufferShirt in buffer.Take(missingCount))
    {
        yield return bufferShirt;
    }
}
```

And the usage would be:

```
IEnumerable<TShirt> tShirts = GetAllTShirts(); // Example method call to populate tShirts

IEnumerable<TShirt> tshirtResults = GetSelection(tShirts, 250, 250);
```

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2szGCq) is a fiddle to experiment with.